# Combine least-squares fit of same quantity measured by different models?

Tags: modeling, least-squares

This question involves fitting experimental data to a model.

A physical quantity $u(x,t)$ is measured by two different methods, resulting in signals (observed values) $y_1$ and $y_2$. The models we are fitting to are $f_1(u; p)$ and $f_2(u; p)$, where $p$ is a vector of parameters being fitted. The models include calculations of $u(x, t)$ from $x$ and $t$.

What is the proper quantity to minimize for a maximum liklihood fit?

When we fit to a single model, we are minimizing $S=\Sigma (y_{1,i}-f_{1,i})^2$, i e, non-linear least squares.

The models are highly non-linear, and we have no information on the error in the measurements.

Comment: When you refer to "models" $f_i$, are these conditional distributions or are they only notional means (or similar measures of location)?

Comment: "Models" refers to the functions used to calculate the expected values of the signals. That is, given a set of $(x_i,t_i)$ we compute $u_i$ and then $f_{1,i}$ and $f_{2,i}$. The idea of "fitting to a model" means we find the set of parameters $p$ that matches the experimental $y_i$ the best.

Comment: Thanks. Note however, that in general the idea of "fitting a model" doesn't just mean just estimating expected values. (Yes, it involves estimating parameters, but that usually implies fitting conditional distribution). In this instance - without some distributional model - there's no likelihood to maximize.

Comment: I understand your point about needing a distributional model, but since we don't have one, and we still need to estimate "best-fit" parameter values, we have been using least-squares. I suppose this means we are implicitly assuming normal distribution, but that's the best we can do for now.

Comment: This suggests "best fit" means something nearer to "conveniently fit by some criterion" in which case there's no issue with bringing likelihood in at all.

Comment: OK, the probability density functions for $f_1$ and $f_2$ errors are $g_1(x,t)$ and $g_2(x,t)$. Can you provide any insight now?

Comment: You can write $g=\exp(-\psi())$, if the observations are independent then the negative of the log likelihood is $S=\sum_i \psi(u(x_i,t_i))$; maximizing likelihood is equivalent to minimizing $S$ (as covered in other questions on site). However the question seems somewhat ill-defined at present (e.g. if we're fitting by least squares why care about likelihood; if we're fitting by likelihood why are we discussing least squares; is $u$ really an error term in the statistical sense or is it something else ... etc etc) and I am unsure of the circumstances, or if this even makes sense in context.